# How to check if name is over then 6 letters and if over, show only first 6 and ... after

Tags: php

Lets say i have this name :

```
$name = Breddpitishere;
```

And i want to check if user name is over then 6 letters and echo this :

```
Breddp...
```

how to this ? Thanks allot.

**EDIT: Thanks you all working i will flag the answer.**

Comment: Do you have an attempted solution, and can you tell us why it didn't work?

Comment: Have you tried `if(strlen($name) > 6) echo substr($name, 0, 6) . '...';` ? Also since it concerns names, you might want to use multi byte functions like `mb_strlen()`.

Comment: `$name = Breddpitishere;` This is irregular use of the language and should throw a Warning. Its a string, wrap it in commas.

Comment: now i did and its worked :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (strlen($name) > 6)
  echo substr($name,0,6)."...";
else
  echo $name;
```

Comment: tiny easy and worked perfect thanks for fast solution :)

Answer (score 1):

A Short version, of correct answers:

`echo (strlen($name) > 6) ? substr($name,0,6).'...' : $name;`

Answer (score 0):

you can use php inbuilt `strlen()` function,

```
$name = "Breddpitishere";
if(strlen($name)>6){
   echo substr($name, 0, 6)."...";
}else{
   echo $name;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [substr](https://www.php.net/substr).

```
$name = Breddpitishere;
$shortName=substr($name, 0, 6)."...";
echo $shortName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the PHP substr() method, and echo.

https://www.php.net/substr